# How do I report a Welch's test?

Tags: reporting, baum-welch

I ran a Welch's test with Alpha= 0.05 followed by a Games Howell test. The Welch's test is not significant (p-value=0.104)
Is it enough to just mention that the groups were not significantly different (Welche's test, P>0.05) or other parameters like F-stat, df1 and df2 would be necessary to be inserted in my report?

Comment: Why report $p > 0.05$ rather than the actual $p$-value? And if you mean a Welch $t$-test, than you should include the effect size (i.e. how big was the (non-significant) difference in means).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to figure out how to calculate effect size after conducting a Welch’s ANOVA? Which numbers should I use for the formula? It wasn't a Welch's t-test though. I have 3 groups, n=7 for each

Comment: You had better ask that as a separate question, which will make it easier for potential future visitors to find. Could you edit your question to be more specific that you are trying to do an *ANOVA* and not a $t$-test? When you say *Welch*, I think most people will think of the $t$-test. Maybe you should also include what kind of report you are writing: is it a peer-reviewed article, a university assignment, something for use in a meeting at work?

Comment: Thanks! I just posted a new question addressing all of these.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363249/reporting-the-effect-size-for-welchs-anova